# hyperlink manager changes the link in dotnetnuke

Tags: url, hyperlink, dotnetnuke

as  i enter the url in hyperlink manager and click check the how many time this link is clicked option ,my url automatically changed when i see next time.
i check that its only change the url which is in portal alias table exists and replace my url
with dot .
any one have any idea.if u need more description i  can provide ??

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the URL is, and how it is being changed?

Comment: localhost/subfolder/child1/child2/child3/file.pdf is changed to  //subfolder/child1/child2/child3/file.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In order to track the number of times a link is clicked, it must use a LinkClick type link.  If you don't check the "Track the number of times this link is clicked" option then it will use a "normal" URL.